# Does ECMAScript 6 support all language features of ECMAScript 5? Is ES6 a superset of ES5?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, cross-browser

I am asking this question as I was trying to understand a browser's support on different releases(ES6, ES5,ES3... etc.) of JS standards. Is it right that when a browser suports ES6 it also supports ES5? When a browser (e.g. IE 11) supports ES5, does it also support ES3?

Comment: Yes, ECMAScript needs to stay backwards-compatible.

Comment: Yes unless a method is deprecated.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30149034/1048572

Comment: @ISAE They might be deprecated, but they don't get removed from the browsers. Heck, even the spec has an annex detailing the exact standard-deviating semantics that an engine needs to implement to be web-compatible.