# What is the best way to load Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a first generation iPad mini. It's a about 8 years old and although it displays my page correctly some functionalities that require JavaScript doesn't seem to work. If I understood correctly I need to load Babel or something like that. Is that true? But what's the best way to load Babel? should I just use a script tag like so:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Is that enough?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html

Comment: Yes, it is enough. 
Try by executing a simple function. like given in the installation guide https://babeljs.io/en/setup#installation

Comment: Also, let us know which version of safari you are using

Comment: Do you load babel in the HTML head or before the body tag closes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EcmaScript-6 backward compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149034/ecmascript-6-backward-compatibility)

Comment: You don't load Babel, it's a pre-compiler, you compile your js using babel then add the output of that. It actually sounds like you just need to read the babel docs https://babeljs.io/docs/en/

Comment: Sure but then why does this `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>` exist? It has to be loaded somewhere, right? I can't use npm on the server

Comment: @Liam That's not true. Babel can transpile your JS running in your browser as well. Not that that's advisable...

Comment: @aross How does Babel "transpile" invalid syntax in the browser? o.O

Comment: @Andreas by using `text/babel` instead of `text/javascript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: don't load Babel in the browser in a production env**

It depends on what exactly doesn't work. If it's simply syntax and some ES6 classes/functions, that's probably solved by Babel which transforms syntax and has some polyfills. You can transpile your JS server-side if you're concerned about load times (which makes sense for older devices). If you can't do it on the server, you can just deploy a JS file you transpiled on your workstation. Also, if you go [here](https://babeljs.io/en/setup) and click on "In the browser", you'll see this:

> Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts server-side.

You should probably also have a look at [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=const). Then you can decide how much time you want to invest in the first place. `const` for example is supported by 99.8% of users globally.

However, it can be that your page uses JS to do some complex interaction that depends on pointers, touch events and such. In that case you probably need to rewrite a lot of it. This does not apply to your situation, but generally may impact someone's decision on what browsers to support.

Comment: I don't use that iPad but I was thinking some users will eventually visit the page from older devices so I thought loading BabelJS won't hurt anything. Or does loading Babel affects loading times? I just need it for stuff like const, let, etc...

Comment: @ZoltanKing That shouldn't be a problem. If you're worried about load times on old devices, transpiling server-side (and minifying as well of course) will help a lot, and you won't have to think about how to load the JS in the browser.